# Weird error in spree, custom payment method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, spree

I am wroking with Ruby on Rails 4 and Spree, I have to use external payment service - liqpay - https://www.liqpay.com/, so I created custom Gateway, customized Checkout Controller and and Created controller for liqpay callback. After the payment is done, i have pre-final page and a button "finish the order" and everything seems to bo fine. But when I click this buttm I have an error, here is what in the log

```
      ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute: server):
          activerecord (4.0.6) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:47:in `rescuein _assign_attribute'
        activerecord (4.0.6) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:42:in `_assign_attribute'
        activerecord (4.0.6) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:29:in `block in assign_attributes'
      activerecord (4.0.6) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:23:in `each'
        activerecord (4.0.6) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:23:in `assign_attributes'
        activerecord (4.0.6) lib/active_record/core.rb:469:in `init_attributes'
      activerecord (4.0.6) lib/active_record/core.rb:185:in `initialize'
        activerecord (4.0.6) lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:30:in `new'
        activerecord (4.0.6) lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:30:in `new'
      spree_core (2.2.4) app/models/spree/gateway.rb:25:in `provider'
        spree_core (2.2.4) app/models/spree/gateway.rb:2:in `purchase'
        spree_core (2.2.4) app/models/spree/payment/processing.rb:158:in `block in gateway_action'
      spree_core (2.2.4) app/models/spree/payment/processing.rb:191:in `protect_from_connection_error'
        spree_core (2.2.4) app/models/spree/payment/processing.rb:155:in `gateway_action'
        spree_core (2.2.4) app/models/spree/payment/processing.rb:33:in `purchase!'
      spree_core (2.2.4) app/models/spree/payment/processing.rb:10:in `process!'
        spree_core (2.2.4) app/models/spree/order.rb:391:in `block in process_payments!'
        spree_core (2.2.4) app/models/spree/order.rb:388:in `each'
      spree_core (2.2.4) app/models/spree/order.rb:388:in `process_payments!'
        spree_core (2.2.4) app/models/spree/order/checkout.rb:74:in `block (2 levels) in define_state_machine!'
        state_machine (1.2.0) lib/state_machine/eval_helpers.rb:79:in `call'
      state_machine (1.2.0) lib/state_machine/eval_helpers.rb:79:in `evaluate_method'
        state_machine (1.2.0) lib/state_machine/callback.rb:191:in `block in run_methods'
        state_machine (1.2.0) lib/state_machine/callback.rb:190:in `each'
      state_machine (1.2.0) lib/state_machine/callback.rb:190:in `run_methods'
        state_machine (1.2.0) lib/state_machine/callback.rb:159:in `call'
        state_machine (1.2.0) lib/state_machine/transition.rb:420:in `before'
      state_machine (1.2.0) lib/state_machine/transition.rb:246:in `block in run_callbacks'
        state_machine (1.2.0) lib/state_machine/transition.rb:348:in `block in pausable'
        state_machine (1.2.0) lib/state_machine/transition.rb:348:in `catch'
      state_machine (1.2.0) lib/state_machine/transition.rb:348:in `pausable'
        state_machine (1.2.0) lib/state_machine/transition.rb:246:in `run_callbacks'
        state_machine (1.2.0) lib/state_machine/transition_collection.rb:127:in `run_callbacks'
      state_machine (1.2.0) lib/state_machine/transition_collection.rb:63:in `block (2 levels) in perform'
        state_machine (1.2.0) lib/state_machine/transition_collection.rb:63:in `catch'
        state_machine (1.2.0) lib/state_machine/transition_collection.rb:63:in `block in perform'
      state_machine (1.2.0) lib/state_machine/transition_collection.rb:182:in `block in within_transaction'
        spree_core (2.2.4) app/models/spree/gateway.rb:25:in `provider'
        spree_core (2.2.4) app/models/spree/gateway.rb:2:in `purchase'
      spree_core (2.2.4) app/models/spree/payment/processing.rb:158:in `block in gateway_action'
        spree_core (2.2.4) app/models/spree/payment/processing.rb:191:in `protect_from_connection_error'
        spree_core (2.2.4) app/models/spree/payment/processing.rb:155:in `gateway_action'
      spree_core (2.2.4) app/models/spree/payment/processing.rb:33:in `purchase!'
        spree_core (2.2.4) app/models/spree/payment/processing.rb:10:in `process!'
        spree_core (2.2.4) app/models/spree/order.rb:391:in `block in process_payments!'
      spree_core (2.2.4) app/models/spree/order.rb:388:in `each'
        spree_core (2.2.4) app/models/spree/order.rb:388:in `process_payments!'
        spree_core (2.2.4) app/models/spree/order/checkout.rb:74:in `block (2 levels) in define_state_machine!'
      state_machine (1.2.0) lib/state_machine/eval_helpers.rb:79:in `call'
        state_machine (1.2.0) lib/state_machine/eval_helpers.rb:79:in `evaluate_method'
        state_machine (1.2.0) lib/state_machine/callback.rb:191:in `block in run_methods'
      state_machine (1.2.0) lib/state_machine/callback.rb:190:in `each'
        state_machine (1.2.0) lib/state_machine/callback.rb:190:in `run_methods'
        state_machine (1.2.0) lib/state_machine/callback.rb:159:in `call'
      state_machine (1.2.0) lib/state_machine/transition.rb:420:in `before'
        state_machine (1.2.0) lib/state_machine/transition.rb:246:in `block in run_callbacks'
        state_machine (1.2.0) lib/state_machine/transition.rb:348:in `block in pausable'
      state_machine (1.2.0) lib/state_machine/transition.rb:348:in `catch'
        state_machine (1.2.0) lib/state_machine/transition.rb:348:in `pausable'
        state_machine (1.2.0) lib/state_machine/transition.rb:246:in `run_callbacks'
      state_machine (1.2.0) lib/state_machine/transition_collection.rb:127:in `run_callbacks'
        state_machine (1.2.0) lib/state_machine/transition_collection.rb:63:in `block (2 levels) in perform'
        state_machine (1.2.0) lib/state_machine/transition_collection.rb:63:in `catch'
      state_machine (1.2.0) lib/state_machine/transition_collection.rb:63:in `block in perform'
        state_machine (1.2.0) lib/state_machine/transition_collection.rb:182:in `block in within_transaction'
        state_machine (1.2.0) lib/state_machine/transition.rb:227:in `block in within_transaction'
      state_machine (1.2.0) lib/state_machine/machine.rb:1904:in `within_transaction'
        state_machine (1.2.0) lib/state_machine/transition.rb:226:in `within_transaction'
        state_machine (1.2.0) lib/state_machine/transition_collection.rb:181:in `within_transaction'
      state_machine (1.2.0) lib/state_machine/transition_collection.rb:62:in `perform'
        state_machine (1.2.0) lib/state_machine/transition.rb:219:in `perform'
        state_machine (1.2.0) lib/state_machine/event.rb:172:in `fire'
      state_machine (1.2.0) lib/state_machine/event.rb:247:in `block in add_actions'
        state_machine (1.2.0) lib/state_machine/machine.rb:765:in `call'
        state_machine (1.2.0) lib/state_machine/machine.rb:765:in `block (2 levels) in define_helper'
      spree_frontend (2.2.4) app/controllers/spree/checkout_controller.rb:30:in `update'
        actionpack (4.0.6) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
        actionpack (4.0.6) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
      actionpack (4.0.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
        actionpack (4.0.6) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
        activesupport (4.0.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:563:in `_run__4393275023746077082__process_action__callbacks'
      activesupport (4.0.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
        actionpack (4.0.6) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
        actionpack (4.0.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
      actionpack (4.0.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
        activesupport (4.0.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
        activesupport (4.0.6) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
      activesupport (4.0.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
        actionpack (4.0.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
        actionpack (4.0.6) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
      activerecord (4.0.6) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
        actionpack (4.0.6) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
        actionpack (4.0.6) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in `process'
      actionpack (4.0.6) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
        actionpack (4.0.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
        actionpack (4.0.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in `dispatch'
      actionpack (4.0.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `call'
        actionpack (4.0.6) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
        actionpack (4.0.6) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
      actionpack (4.0.6) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
        actionpack (4.0.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:676:in `call'
        railties (4.0.6) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
      railties (4.0.6) lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
        actionpack (4.0.6) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
        actionpack (4.0.6) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
      actionpack (4.0.6) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
        actionpack (4.0.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:676:in `call'
        warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
      warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
        warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
        rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
      rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
        rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
        actionpack (4.0.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
      actionpack (4.0.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241:in `call'
        rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
        rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
      actionpack (4.0.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in `call'
        activerecord (4.0.6) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
        activerecord (4.0.6) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in `call'
      actionpack (4.0.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
        activesupport (4.0.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__2243693745465876108__call__callbacks'
        activesupport (4.0.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
      actionpack (4.0.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
        actionpack (4.0.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
        actionpack (4.0.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
      actionpack (4.0.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
        railties (4.0.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
        railties (4.0.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
      activesupport (4.0.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
        activesupport (4.0.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
        activesupport (4.0.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
      railties (4.0.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
        actionpack (4.0.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
        rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
      rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
        activesupport (4.0.6) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
        rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
      railties (4.0.6) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
        railties (4.0.6) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
        unicorn (4.8.3) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:576:in `process_client'
      unicorn (4.8.3) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:670:in `worker_loop'
        unicorn (4.8.3) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:525:in `spawn_missing_workers'
        unicorn (4.8.3) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:140:in `start'
      unicorn (4.8.3) bin/unicorn:126:in `<top (required)>'
        /var/www/genetic_shop/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/unicorn:23:in `load'
        /var/www/genetic_shop/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/unicorn:23:in `<main>'
```

Controller method called after finish payment looks pretty simple

```
  def payment_network_callback
     if @order.paid?
       @order.next
     end
     redirect_to checkout_state_path(@order.state)
  end
```

and Api Controller method called after payment status is changed is that(looks like a hack, but I do not know how to do it right)

```
            def liqpay_api_callback
              @order = Spree::Order.find params[:order_id]
              @order.payments.create! source: Spree::LiqpayCheckout.create, amount: @order.total,
                                      payment_method: Spree::PaymentMethod.where(type: 'Spree::Gateway::Liqpay').first if @order.payments.length == 0
              if params[:status] == 'success' || params[:status] == 'sandbox'
                @order.update_attribute :payment_state, 'paid'
                head :ok
              else
                head :unprocessable_entity
              end
            rescue => e
              logger.fatal e.class.to_s
              logger.fatal e.to_s
              logger.fatal e.backtrace.join('/n')
              head :internal_server_error
            end
```

So, do you have any ideas, what is the 'unknown attribute: server' and how to do it correctly? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution. May be it is not good style, but it works. So, the main logic is in the CheckoutController decorator in callback method, it is called after payment in liqpay is completed

```
    def payment_network_callback
      if @order.paid?
        @order.payments.first.process!
        @order.deliver_order_confirmation_email
        @order.next
        @order.finalize!
        session[:order_id] = nil
      end
      redirect_to "/orders/#{@order.number}"
    end
```

There is also another method - my app API method, liqpay call it after paiment change it's status it is in another controller

```
          def liqpay_api_callback
            @order = Spree::Order.find params[:order_id]
            sign = get_callback_sign(params[:amount], params[:order_id], params[:status], params[:transaction_id], params[:sender_phone])
            @order.payments.create! source: Spree::LiqpayCheckout.create, amount: @order.total,
                                    payment_method: Spree::PaymentMethod.where(type: 'Spree::Gateway::Liqpay').first if @order.payments.length == 0
            sign[-1]=''
            if (params[:status] == 'success' || params[:status] == 'sandbox') && (sign.eql? params[:signature])
              @order.update_attribute :payment_state, 'paid'
              head :ok
            else
              head :unprocessable_entity
            end
          rescue => e
            logger.fatal e.class.to_s
            logger.fatal e.to_s
            logger.fatal e.backtrace.join('/n')
            head :internal_server_error
          end

        end
```

and this is how Gateway looks like

```
   module Spree
        class Gateway::Liqpay < Gateway

          attr_accessor :server, :test_mode


          preference :server,:string, default: 'test'
          preference :test_mode, :boolean, default: true


          def provider
            @provider = self
          end

          def purchase(amount, source, options = {})
            Class.new do
              def success?; true; end
              def authorization; nil; end
            end.new
          end

          def auto_capture?
            true
          end

          def payment_profiles_supported?
            true
          end

          def provider_class
            self.class
          end

          def method_type
            'liqpay'
          end
        end
      end
```